# How to get actual layout dimension after fit to screen?

Tags: android, layout

I need to get the exact width of a `RelativeLayout` after it auto sizes to the screen.  I have the dimensions set for the layout but on devices with a smaller screen than the target size, auto-sizing occurs and throws off my position calculations within the layout window because `layout.getWidth()` returns the width that is in the xml file not the actual drawn width.

Does anyone know how to get the drawn width?  If not, is there a way to get the screen width in pixels?

Comment: POST YOUR CODE SNIPPET

Answer (score 0):

If you need the display dimensions in pixels you can use getSize:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

if u r not using activity you can get the default Display via WINDOW_SERVICE:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Display Dimension in Pixel**

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point point = new Point();

display.getSize(point);

int width = point.x;

int height = point.y;

**OutSide From Activity use this code.**

WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```